# How differently would ocean currents be affected by smaller, shallower abyssal plains?

Tags: science-based, ocean, alternate-earth, currents

On Earth, the abyssal plain is the planet's largest habitat, comprising of 70% of the oceans.  Another important point is that plain can be found between 10,000 and 20,000 feet deep.

In this alternate Earth scenario, volcanic eruptions had been reshaping the face of the planet between 56 and 23 million years ago.  As a result, the abyssal plains make up only 23% of the oceans and don't get any deeper than 5,280 feet, or one solid mile.  The rest of this alternate Earth's oceans comprise of continental shelves (themselves making up less than five percent of the ocean), oceanic ridges, trenches and seamounts that vary in depth from 50 feet to one mile beneath the surface and in area from 3,400 to 15,500 square miles.

So the important thing is--will these differences affect the ocean currents in any way?  If yes, then how?

Comment: Your oceans would either contain less water than real Earth, which might cause vaious effects on climate by itself, or enough deep trenches, ice caps and/or larger ocean coverage to contain all the water.

Comment: The Community is starting the process of updating our Tour and primary Help Center page. This will include policy decisions and it's a great opportunity to help us define the next stage of [worldbuilding.se]. Please join us at [this Meta page](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10334/40609) and share your thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Shallower waters mean that the currents will have a smaller flow rate, due to the relatively higher influence of the floor on the shear, and the less space available to have two opposite flowing currents.

Think of the difference between using a narrow straw and a broader one to drink the same beverage.